# Syncing renamed files without copying

Tags: files, rsync, rename, file-copy, synchronization

I've renamed a bunch of files and moved some to other folders. Now I want to sync all these changes to another filesystem, that already contains the original files. Something like rsync with --delete. However, I would like the renaming and moving to subdirectories to take place locally on the other filesystem. Thus, files that are already there should not be copied, just moved/renamed.

Does rsync support this behaviour? Or is there another tool that does?

Comment: [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison) supports this (you may want the `-force` option) **but** you have to run it before you rename or move files so it can see what has changed.

Comment: If you want to use `rsync`, search the web for `rsync renamed files` - there are some options.